# Kotlin (null cannot be cast to non-null type) Custom Calendar Implementation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view, calendar

I am trying to use the library https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView (which was made in Kotlin) in Java. In this library there is an example to select a date. In the example, it had shown to do this:

```
    private fun selectDate(date: LocalDate) {
    if (selectedDate != date) {
        val oldDate = selectedDate
        selectedDate = date
        oldDate?.let { exThreeCalendar.notifyDateChanged(it) }
        exThreeCalendar.notifyDateChanged(date)
        updateAdapterForDate(date)
    }
}
```

After trying to replicate this in my own android project, I wrote this:

```
    private void selectDate(LocalDate date){
        if(selectedDate != date){
            // oldDate is null
            // date is not null
            LocalDate oldDate = selectedDate;
            selectedDate = date;
            if (oldDate != null){
                calendarView.notifyDateChanged(oldDate);
            }
            calendarView.notifyDateChanged(date);
            updateAdapterForDate(date);
            }
        }
```

When my fragment launches, it calls the selectDate() method with today's date as the parameter (which is not null).
It gives an error on

```
calendarView.notifyDateChanged(date);
```

saying

```
 null cannot be cast to non-null type com.kizitonwose.calendarview.ui.CalendarAdapter
```

I am wondering how to achieve the same outcome

```
oldDate?.let { exThreeCalendar.notifyDateChanged(it) }
```

in Java or if there is something else incorrect with my code.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What error does it give? Maybe all you need to do is put `@Nonnull` before `LocalDate` in the method signature.

Comment: The question has been updated to show the error and even though "date" is not null in this case it still passes that error.

Comment: @Tanishk it's not the `date` that's causing the error, it's that `calendarView` is `null`. Read the exception carefully: it says that `null` cannot be cast to `CalendarAdapter`.

Comment: @SpaceBison Actually it's something inside `calendarView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the type in the error message. It isn't `date` which is null, but something of type `CalendarAdapter`, I would suspect

```
private val calendarAdapter: CalendarAdapter
    get() = adapter as CalendarAdapter
```

It looks like `adapter` should be set in [`setup`](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView/blob/6f743b9eb8ebbf536f52fdafd078ecd37faa6ceb/library/src/main/java/com/kizitonwose/calendarview/CalendarView.kt#L577), maybe you aren't calling it?

Comment: It was that I had called the selectDate function right after initializing the view and not right after calling the setup method of the CalendarView class. Thank you for your help!

Comment: By the way: did you not get the full stack trace for some reason? It should show the exception inside `CalendarView`, not in your code.

Comment: It did show the exception inside CalendarView at ```com.kizitonwose.calendarview.CalendarView.getCalendarAdapter(CalendarView.kt:390)```

Comment: For future reference: please post the stack trace in such cases.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that in the future.